# Using JQuery for multiple Image sliding at unison?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, animation

I can find plenty of Image Sliders but I could not find what I needed. Perhaps someone could help ---

I would like to have multiple image [thumbnails] sliding together in unison. Would someone please help ? I would like to have something like .animate() for multiple images together.

Comment: I would look to flash for that. It is much more efficient for animation. Multiple animations going on in javascript can really slow things down on computers that are a little older.

Comment: Flash!? Use CSS transitions! (And jQuery as a fallback if you must support users that are holding back the web.)

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to select multiple elements at once and animate them together.

```
$('#something img').animate(...);
$('#img-1, #img-2, #img-3').animate(...);
```